# Unable to install packages in atom

Tags: package, atom-editor

[Unable to install packages in Atom I would be happy to help what this problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npq4Y.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It explicitly says that the package is deprecated and therefore you can't install it...are you looking for hacks to install it anyway? I would rather recommend searching for similar packages that are still up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

The packages which you tried to install use deprecations; they are just too old. You could use "*atom-beautify*" instead which has the same purpose as the packages you tried to install.